# D'où vient l'expression « top là » ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Écoutant la radio j'entends les paroles d'un vieux film français ou la personne dit:

> Bon alors c'est d'accord? Allez! Top là!

D'où vient cette expression? Est-ce que le mon "top" vient du mot "stop"? Je ne connais qu'une expression en anglais qui pourrait aussi faire penser que l'expression vient de l'anglais... "It will be 4 at the top".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'orthographe correcte est « tope là ». Le verbe « [toper](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.com/toper/fr-fr/) » (que je ne connaissais pas), ou « tôper » comme le souligne Alexis, signifie « accepter un défi en se tapant dans la main. »

Comment: Ah! Je vois même que Le Littré l'écrit avec un accent circumflex: `tôper`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke en effet.

Comment: Ça alors, et moi qui aurais écrit « tope-la ».

Answer (score 7):

Le verbe *toper* vient de l'ancien français *tuper* « placer en jetant ». Il signifie à la fois accepter un enjeu et le fait de taper dans la main de quelqu'un avec qui on passe un marché pour l'accepter.
Pour dire qu'on accepte un marché on a d'abord dit « topez ! » (attesté dès le 17<sup>e</sup>siècle), puis « topez là », là désignant la main.

Comment: Ah! J'avais toujours pensé que le « là » voulait dire « à cette valeur » ou « avec cet arrangement ».